# Insert query for tables with connected in foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have following two tables with linked in foreign key address. Assume a person can have different address. So the table structure looks like following where for instance person aa have two addresses.

#### table A

```
id name age adress
-------------------
1  aa   bb  10
2  xx   cc  11
```

#### table B

```
id adress lane1 lane2 lane3 
----------------------------
1  10     l2    l2    l3
2  10     v1    v2    v3
```

Please tell me how to write the sql insert statement where i can cover the scenario which person aa have two address. (insert statement for populate data as i show in above tables)

Comment: You mean "update", I think.  It's not clear to me what issues there'd be with inserting into either table.

Comment: Are you asking what queries would be needed to populate each of those tables?

Comment: well OMG and Thomas i need to insert data in same time for both table using a insert query

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at the same time"? Does that mean you have a person, and want to populate their data in Table A and their addresses in Table B?

Comment: yes Thomas..well i guess i have to use two insert queries knw..cant use a single query for that

Answer (score 0):

When you have circular foreign keys you need what PostgreSQL calls deferred constraints don't know if mysql has these. But it is also a sign of bad schema design.

Better structure would be:

```
table person

id name age

1  aa   bb
2  xx   cc

table address

id person lane1 lane2 lane3 
1  1     l2    l2    l3
2  1     v1    v2    v3
```

Then you will need only one foreign-key and the inserts shouldn't give you any trouble.

Comment: thanks Eelke..if i change the structure to above how does the sql insert statement should look like?

Comment: You will have to use seperate inserts for seperate tables. Wrap them in a transaction to make them atomic. I assume you have some basic knowledge about queries. If not go find some tutorials.